# Explanation for ObjectCreationHandling using Newtonsoft JSON?

Tags: c#, json.net

I was tracking down a bug and I noticed that Newtonsoft JSON will append items to a `List<>` that's been initialized in the default constructor. I did a little more digging and discussed with some people on the C# chat and we noticed that this behavior doesn't apply to all other collection types.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ikNyiT

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class TestClass
{
    public Collection<string> Collection = new Collection<string>(new [] { "ABC", "DEF" });
    public List<string> List = new List<string>(new [] { "ABC", "DEF" });
    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> ReadOnlyCollection = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(new [] { "ABC", "DEF" });
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var serialized = @"{
            Collection: [ 'Goodbye', 'AOL' ],
            List: [ 'Goodbye', 'AOL' ],
            ReadOnlyCollection: [ 'Goodbye', 'AOL' ]
        }";


        var testObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(serialized);

        Console.WriteLine("testObj.Collection: " + string.Join(",", testObj.Collection));
        Console.WriteLine("testObj.List: " + string.Join(",", testObj.List));
        Console.WriteLine("testObj.ReadOnlyCollection: " + string.Join(",", testObj.ReadOnlyCollection));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
testObj.Collection: ABC,DEF
testObj.List: ABC,DEF,Goodbye,AOL
testObj.ReadOnlyCollection: Goodbye,AOL
```

As you can see the `Collection<>` property is unaffected by deserialization, the `List<>` is appended to and `ReadOnlyCollection<>` is replaced. Is this intended behavior? What was the reasoning?

Comment: I suspect the answer would be "just because", also it would be interesting to know if there is a reason behind behavior for List/Collection (ReadOnlyCollection's behavior is somewhat self-explanatory from my point of view). Side note: consider updating title to be more specific - "curious" is somewhat hard to guess if one would want to find this based on problem...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I am having some issues figuring out the nuance between ReadOnlyCollection and Collection. The issue appears to be with the ObjectCreationHandling setting and so I added that to the title.

Comment: This issue was also discussed in the [c# chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/20857312#20857312).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It basically boils down to type instantiation and the [`ObjectCreationHandling`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_ObjectCreationHandling.htm) setting. There are three settings for `ObjectCreationHandling`

> Auto   0   Reuse existing objects, create new objects when needed.
>       Reuse   1   Only reuse existing objects.
>       Replace 2   Always create new objects.

The default is `auto` ([Line 44](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/ee170dc5510bb3ffd35fc1b0d986f34e33c51ab9/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonSerializerSettings.cs)).

Auto is only overwritten after a series of checks which determine if the current type has a `TypeInitializer` which is null. At that point it checks if there is a parameterless constructor.

> /// 
>    /// Create a factory function that can be used to create instances of a JsonConverter described by the
>    /// argument type.
>    /// The returned function can then be used to either invoke the converter's default ctor, or any
>    /// parameterized constructors by way of an object array.
>    ///

Essentially it acts like this (what it looks like is about 1500 lines of code in 6 classes).

```
ObjectCreationHandling och = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto;
if( typeInitializer == null )
{
 if( parameterlessConstructor )
 {
  och = ObjectCreationHandling.Reuse;
 }
 else
 {
  och = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace;
 }
}
```

This setting is a part of the JsonSerializerSettings which are composed inside of the visitor pattern constructor for DeserializeObject. As shown above, each setting has a different function.

Getting back to List, Collection, and ReadOnlyCollection, we will look at the set of conditional statements for each.

*List*

`testObj.List.GetType().TypeInitializer == null` is false. As a result, `List` receives the default ObjectCreationHandling.Auto and the instantiated List for the testObj instance is used during deserialization, as well as a new List being instantiated with the `serialized` string.

```
testObj.List: ABC,DEF,Goodbye,AOL
```

*Collection*

`testObj.Collection.GetType().TypeInitializer == null` is true indicating there was no reflected type initializer available, so we go to the next condition which is to check if there is a parameterless constructor. `testObj.Collection.GetType().GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) == null` is false. As a result `Collection` receives the value of ObjectCreationHandling.Reuse (*only reuse existing objects*). The instantiated instance for Collection is used from testObj, but the `serialized` string is not able to be instantiated.

```
testObj.Collection: ABC,DEF
```

*ReadOnlyCollection*

`testObj.ReadOnlyCollection.GetType().TypeInitializer == null` is true indicating there was no reflected type initializer available, so we go to the next condition which is to check if there is a parameterless constructor. `testObj.ReadOnlyCollection.GetType().GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) == null` is also true. As a result ReadOnlyCollection recieves the value of ObjectCreationHandling.Replace (*always create new objects*). Only the instantiated value from the `serialized` string is used.

```
testObj.ReadOnlyCollection: Goodbye,AOL
```

Answer (score 3):

Although this has been resolved, I wanted to post this answer to a duplicate question originally, but that question was closed, so I am publishing my answer here, as it contains some internal look into this.

Because Json.NET is open source, we can luckily track down the reason down to its root :-) .

If you check the Json.NET source, you can find class `JsonSerializerInternalReader` which handles the deserialization ([complete source here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/17f87f53211af9645ab8b6947d79e9f4e0e3c6be/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs)). This class has a method `SetPropertyValue`, which sets the deserialized value on the newly created object (code abbreviated):

```
private bool SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, ..., object target)
{
    ...
    if (CalculatePropertyDetails(
          property, 
          ...,
          out useExistingValue,
          ... ))
    {
        return false;
    }

    ...

    if (propertyConverter != null && propertyConverter.CanRead)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        value = CreateValueInternal(
           ...,
           (useExistingValue) ? currentValue : null);
    }

    if ((!useExistingValue || value != currentValue)
        && ShouldSetPropertyValue(property, value))
    {
        property.ValueProvider.SetValue(target, value);
        ...    
        return true;
    }
    return useExistingValue;
}
```

As you can see, there is a boolean flag `useExistingValue` which determines whether or not the existing value is reused or replaced.

Inside the `CalculatePropertyDetails` method is the following snippet:

```
        if ((objectCreationHandling != ObjectCreationHandling.Replace)
            && (tokenType == JsonToken.StartArray || tokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            && property.Readable)
        {
            currentValue = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(target);
            gottenCurrentValue = true;

            if (currentValue != null)
            {
                ...

                useExistingValue = (
                   !propertyContract.IsReadOnlyOrFixedSize &&
                   !propertyContract.UnderlyingType.IsValueType());
            }
        }
```

In case of the `List<T>` underlying collection, the `IsReadOnlyOrFixedSize` returns `false` and `IsValueType()` returns `false` - hence the underlying existing value is reused.

For `Array`, `IsValueType()` is also `false`, but the `IsReadOnlyOrFixedSize` is `true` for obvious reasons, therefore the `useExistingValue` flag is set to `false` and the `CreateValueInternal` call in the `SetPropertyValue` method receives a `null` reference which is an indicator not to reuse the existing value, but to create a new one, which is then set on the new instance.

As was mentioned, this behavior can be altered using `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace`, as this is checked before setting the `useExistingValue` in the `CalculatePropertyDetails` method.