# .NET Core 3.1 - Extra items added to List property of model during JSON to .NET serialization

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a .NET Core API. I set the following in Startup.cs to handle serialization:

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
});
```

I have the following endpoint to update an object:

```
[HttpPut, Route( "car" )]
public ActionResult<Car> UpdateCar( [FromBody] Car car )
```

Using the following model class:

```
public class Car
{
    public List<Owner> PreviousOwners  { get; set; }
    public List<string> Details { get; set; }

    public Car() 
    {
        PreviousOwners = new List<Owner>();
        Details = new List<string> { "Used" };
    }
}
```

When I PUT to this endpoint, I want to ensure that the "Used" value is in the list, at the minimum. This is why I modify the default constructor as such.

However, when I PUT to this endpoint, without defining any further "Details" values (say, I add another PreviousOwner) then I get the following at my breakpoint set at when the endpoint is hit (before any further code is processed):

```
{
    "PreviousOwners": [ *Populates Correctly* ],
    "Details": [
        "Used",
        "Used"
    ],
}
```

**Why is an additional "Used" being added here? Is an empty default constructor absolutely required?**

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/29113182/507793

Comment: Your Car already has "Used" because of the constructor. Hence when you get the PUT request, you need will get two of those. This isn't a JSON parsing issue as such. You need to handle your default construction better.