# Unexptected result when trying to deserialize json file in json.net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize json file using Json.net. However result is not what I would like to achieve. My code can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/psFlLu). My root class contains a list that I populate with some default entries in the constructor.  When I deserialize JSON for this class, the deserialized instance contains list entries that have some null values, even though there are no null values in the JSON. As you can see some of values "Min", "Max" and "RealValue" are nulls. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [JSON.NET Why does it Add to List instead of Overwriting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113063/json-net-why-does-it-add-to-list-instead-of-overwriting) or [Explanation for ObjectCreationHandling using Newtonsoft JSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848547/explanation-for-objectcreationhandling-using-newtonsoft-json).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't initialize the properties of Material class in the constructor. This way the serializer will execute the constructor and the values of the passed json will be ignored.

Comment: Or use `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` as in [JSON.NET Why does it Add to List instead of Overwriting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29113063/json-net-why-does-it-add-to-list-instead-of-overwriting).